# Blackberry Listfield with variable height for each row?

Tags: java, list, blackberry, height, listfield

I need to implement custom ListField which has height variable for every each row. 
Selected row should has different height then other rows.

Answer (score 8):

Well you need to look your self in the mirror and answer "Are Undocumented Methods OK?"

if the answer is yes use "ListField.setRowHeight(index,height)"  this is available in 4.2.1 4.7 and 5.0 atleast.

hope that helps.

Comment: You mean undocumented ListField.setRowHeight(index,height)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll tempt fate and make use of this (as I think the alternative is to build my own custom list control).

Comment: be warned you can only have up to 255 pixels in row height.