# Expand listfield row height dynamically in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to expand list field row height dynamically..When you click on one of the items in the List Field it expands to give you more information. Anyone know how to do it?Any sample code related to it would be helpful.

Comment: in case it helps, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737643/blackberry-listfield-with-variable-height-for-each-row

Answer (score 1):

The ListField uses the same hieght for all elements in the list. What you may want to look at is the TreeField. There is sample code distributed with the Blackberry Java Development Environment (in projects: communicationapidemo, serviceroutingdemo, and sqlitedemo).

Comment: Thank you Richard,can you kindly tell me which project in JDE uses tree field,i searched in samples,but didn't find.By the way i am using eclipse plugin