# Custom ListField Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde, listfield

IS it possible to create custom `ListField` in which row height should be variable according to parsed data?
How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible to have different row heights for a [`ListField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html).

> From the API documentation:
>   
>   
>   **Behaviour** 
>   
>   Displays a vertical list of set height items.

Also, the method [`public void setRowHeight(int rowHeight)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html#setRowHeight%28int%29) which sets the height of each row in the list field indicates that it is not possible.

Customised [`VerticalFieldManager`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html) can be used in this case, though for large set of fields it is not efficient.

*[Updated]*

From the post, [change row height in ListField?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/change-row-height-in-ListField/td-p/502060) answered by [simon_hain](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/15193) in BlackBerry Support Forum,

> there is an undocumented method setRowHeight(int, int). it can slow
>   your UI down and, as all undocumented methods, should be used at own
>   risk

Also, check this question asked on SO, [Expand listfield row height dynamically in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2737643/431639)

Comment: Is any alternavtive control like  `ListField` or the custom implementation of ListField available?

Comment: What problems can be occured with undocumented methods?

Comment: Because it's not possible to know what will the method do, we can guess only.

Comment: how we can use `VerticalFieldManager` in such a case?